# How to fix i386-elf-_g++ x86_64-elf-g++ : command not found

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, bootloader

I am following this tutorial on how to write a bootloader http://3zanders.co.uk/2017/10/18/writing-a-bootloader3/

At the end to link all files together this command is used:

```
i386-elf-_g++ x86_64-elf-g++ -m64 kmain.cpp boot4.o -o kernel.bin 
nostdlib -ffreestanding -std=c++11 -mno-red-zone -fno-exceptions - 
nostdlib -fno-rtti -Wall -Wextra -Werror -T linker.ld
```

If underscore is removed, this error occurs

```
i386-elf-g++: error: x86_64-elf: No such file or directory
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Try removing one of the two commands. I'm not sure why they're there, but you only want one. Are you compiling for i386 or x86_64?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what's up with that underscore in `i386-elf-_g++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing one of the two commands it worked. The command is for compiling for i386 only